# Fill missing values with 0 in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have two variable of arrays namely

**this.barChartData** and **this.barChartLabels**

where

this.barChartData has an array,

> [{"data":[1,5,2]}]

and this.barChartLabels has an array,

> ["32","34","37"]

i need to fill the remaining elements with value 0 in the this.barchartData.

based on the initial and the final value in the **`this.barchartLables`** array.

my final array should be,
 **`this.barChartLabels`**

```
["32","34","37","33","35","36"]
```

and

**`this.barChartData`**

```
[{"data":[1,5,2,0,0,0]}]
```

Comment: `while ( arr.length < 5 ) { arr.push(0); }` ?

Comment: so, what's the problem?

Comment: how to generate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the minimum and maximum label and iterate while checking if the label is already in the array. If not, push values.

```js
var data = [1, 5, 2],
    labels = ["32", "34", "37"],
    min = Math.min.apply(null, labels),
    max = Math.max.apply(null, labels);

while (min <= max) {
    if (labels.indexOf(min.toString()) === -1) {
        labels.push(min.toString());
        data.push(0);
    }
    min++;
}

console.log(data);
console.log(labels);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: i am geting an error in this line (min.toString()) === -1)

Comment: please add real data to the question. with the above data, it should work.

Comment: you could replace `labels.indexOf(min.toString()) === -1` with `labels.includes(min.toString())`.

Comment: If the labels are already sorted (which seems likely) then the min/max step can be simpler

Comment: @Dancrumb, right, but the actual data does not proof that.